# Querying table with group by and sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table called Orders

```
  Order  | Date      |    Total
------------------------------------
 34564   | 03/05/2015|  15.00
 77456   | 01/01/2001|   3.00
 25252   | 02/02/2008|   4.00
 34564   | 03/04/2015|   7.00
```

I am trying to select the distinct order sum the total and group by order #, the problem is that it shows two records for 34564 because they are different dates.. How can I sum if they are repeated orders and pick only the max(date) - But sill sum the total of the two instances?

I.E result

```
  Order  | Date      |    Total
------------------------------------
 34564   | 03/05/2015|  22.00
 77456   | 01/01/2001|   3.00
 25252   | 02/02/2008|   4.00
```

Tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Order, Date, SUM(Total)
FROM Orders
GROUP BY Order, Date
```

Of couse the above won't work as you can see but i am not sure how to achieve what i intend.

Comment: I gave a +1 to everyone but accepting whoever answered first.. that was easy lol... thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT [order], MAX(date) AS date, SUM(total) AS total 
FROM Orders o
GROUP BY [order]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `MAX` aggregate function to choose the latest `Date` to appear from each `Order` group:

```
SELECT Order, MAX(Date) AS Date, SUM(Total) AS Total
FROM Orders
GROUP BY Order
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest query should be:

```
SELECT MAX(Order), MAX(Date), SUM(Total)
FROM Orders
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SUM` and `MAX` together:

```
SELECT
    [Order],
    [Date] = MAX([Date]),
    Total = SUM(Total)
FROM tbl
GROUP BY [Order]
```

A word of advice, please refrain from using reserved words like `Order` and `Date` for your columns and table names.

Answer (score 1):

Just add  MAX(Date) to your SELECT clause.
Try this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT Order, MAX(Date), SUM(Total)
FROM Orders
GROUP BY Order, Date
```